# A Double Integral Substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am asked to compute the integral $$\int_\Omega xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy$$ over the domain $\Omega = \{(x,y)\mid 1\leq x^2-y^2\leq 9, 0\leq x \leq 4, y\geq 0\}.$ After splitting the domain and a messy calculation of the resulting iterated integrals I get the answer $2e(e^8-2),$ which looks very much like what one would get after a nice substitution, but I cannot see how. I tried setting $u(x,y) = x, v(x,y) = x^2-y^2,$ and taking half of the resulting double integral but then I'm getting $2e(e^8-1).$ What am I missing?

Comment: What is $dS$? Is it $dxdy$, or $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$? Please clarify by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you tried to invert your substitution to use it with the change of variables formula, you got

$$F(x,y)=\left(x,\sqrt{x^2-y}\right),$$
$$\det J_F =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2-y}}$$

and ended up with the integral

$$ \int_1^9 \int_0^4 \frac 12 xe^y \,dx\,dy= 2 \cdot 2e(e^8-1).$$

If this is so, then you should have checked that $F$ actually sends the rectangle $[0,4] \times [1,9]$ to $\Omega$!

Let's run through the check:

On the line $x=4$, $F$ sends the point $(4, y)$ to $(4,\sqrt{16-y})$, i.e. the line $x=4$.
(Since $y \in [1, 9]$, the second component is well-defined.)

On the line $y=1$, $F$ sends the point $(x, 1)$  to $(x,\sqrt{x^2-1})$, i.e.  the upper half of $x^2-1=y^2$.
We need $x \in [1, 4]$ for the second component to be well-defined.

On the line $y=9$, $F$ sends the point $(x, 9)$ to $(x,\sqrt{x^2-9})$, i.e. the upper half of  $x^2-9=y^2$.
Similarly, we need $x \in [3, 4]$ for the second component to be well-defined.

Now when we come to the line $x=0$, we get $(0, \sqrt{-y})$, which is not well defined at all!

So there are several issues here.

Let's start by finding the preimage of the line $y = 0$, since that's where the problems are.

Set $F(x,y) = (x, 0)$, and we see that we're looking for the curve $x^2=y$.

After some careful consideration, we find that our new region to integrate over is the rectangle $[0,4] \times [1,9]$ intersected with the region under the parabola $y = x^2$.

That means our integral is now

$$ \int_1^3 \int_1^{x^2} \frac 12 x e^y\,dy\,dx + \int_3^4 \int_1^9 \frac 12 x e^y\,dy\,dx,$$

which evaluates to $2e(e^8-2)$, as we expect.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate this integral directly.
Let $\Omega=\Omega_1 \cup\Omega_2 $, where
$$\Omega_1:1\leq x\leq 3,0\leq y\leq \sqrt{x^2-1},$$
$$\Omega_1:3\leq x\leq 4,\sqrt{x^2-9}\leq y\leq \sqrt{x^2-1}.$$
So $$\iint_\Omega xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy
=\iint_{\Omega_1} xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy+\iint_{\Omega_2} xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy.$$
Then we evaluate the two integrals respectively:
$$\iint_{\Omega_1} xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy
=\int_{1}^{3}xe^{x^2}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2-1}}ye^{-y^2}dy\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{3}x(e^{x^2}-1)dx=\frac{1}{4}(e^9-9e);$$
$$\iint_{\Omega_2} xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy
=\int_{3}^{4}xe^{x^2}\left(\int_{\sqrt{x^2-9}}^{\sqrt{x^2-1}}ye^{-y^2}dy\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{3}^{4}x(e^{9}-e)dx=\frac{7}{4}(e^9-e).$$
From above, we can get :
 $$\iint_\Omega xye^{x^2-y^2}dxdy=2e(e^8-2).$$

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had done it this way initially, but the answer was so neat I suspected there was an obvious substitution I was missing.

Comment: That will be nice! I think here is not a good choice using substitution  because it is difficult to characterize the new domain, Especially  the boundary! the calculation is ok, not too  messy .